# Remove or disable ActionBar Hide animation?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-video-player

I have a custom video player,when user enters into fullscreen i am hiding actionbar but due to its animations its being delayed.
how to avoid it in normal ActionBar or SherlockActionBar  ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to make use of Material Design with the new support library. By doing so you can replace your ActionBar with a Toolbar which gives you a lot more control. By using the Toolbar you can achieve your goal with the setVisibility() method.